# Как задать чтобы header в listView не прокручивался?

Tags: android, listview, прокрутка, header

Создал список, но строки уходя за экран. Когда начинаю листать header пропадает.
Скрин как это выглядит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разметка листа:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lv__pipes_flowV"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
    android:scrollingCache="false"/>
```

Код создания листа:

```
ListView lv__pipes_flowV;

        // упаковываем данные в понятную для адаптера структуру
        ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(
                diameter_table.length);
        Map<String, Object> m;
        for (int i = 0; i < diameter_table.length; i++) {
            m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            m.put("column_1", diameter_table[i]);
            m.put("column_2", min_flow_table[i]);
            m.put("column_3", max_flow_table[i]);
            data.add(m);
        }

        // массив имен атрибутов, из которых будут читаться данные
        String[] from = { "column_1", "column_2", "column_3" };
        // массив ID View-компонентов, в которые будут вставлять данные
        int[] to = { R.id.tv_table_row_3_column_1, R.id.tv_table_row_3_column_2, R.id.tv_table_row_3_column_3 };

        // создаем адаптер
        SimpleAdapter sAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), data, R.layout.table_row_3_column, from, to);

        // определяем список и присваиваем ему адаптер
        lv__pipes_flowV = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv__pipes_flowV);

        LayoutInflater ltInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        View header = ltInflater.inflate(R.layout.table_row_3_column, null, false);
        TextView tv_table_row_3_column_1 = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.tv_table_row_3_column_1);
        tv_table_row_3_column_1.setText(R.string.tv_pipes_flowD_Diameter);
        TextView tv_table_row_3_column_2 = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.tv_table_row_3_column_2);
        tv_table_row_3_column_2.setText(R.string.gv_pipes_flowV_header_min_flow_text);
        TextView tv_table_row_3_column_3 = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.tv_table_row_3_column_3);
        tv_table_row_3_column_3.setText(R.string.gv_pipes_flowV_header_max_flow_text);
        lv__pipes_flowV.addHeaderView(header);


        lv__pipes_flowV.setAdapter(sAdapter);
```

Comment: А может вам нужен не header?

Comment: Заголовок табицы вроде как header. Т.е. не часть данных, а название..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет способа прикрепить `header` `ListView` и не давать ему прокручиваться, т.к. реализуется он как ещё один элемент списка и прокручивается вместе с остальными.

Вам надо поместить `header` как отдельный элемент разметки, а не часть `ListView`.

Answer (score 2):

Это называется `Sticky List Header`. Уже существует по меньшей мере 20 библиотек, реализующих такое поведение.
Вот [одна из них](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders).
[Вот так](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=sticky%20list%20header%20android) можно найти их все (или большинство).
А вот это [приложение](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.desarrollodroide.repos) содержит демонстрации многих полезных библиотек, включая несколько из тех, что вам нужны.